# Build 4 models for 4 csv files (with same features) simultaneously without manually importing one dataset at a time

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop, scikit-learn

I have 4 datasets- `bank1.csv`, `bank2.csv`, `bank3.csv` and `bank4.csv` with the same five features namely- `age`, `income`, `creditscore`,`utility_ratio` and `loan_amount`.

Where `y` is  `loan_amount`

and `X` variables are `age`, `income`, `creditscore` and  `utility_ratio`.

Instead of repetitively importing and building a model for each `.csv` (repeating the process four times), I want to do the following:

(I) programmatically import all four datasets and iterate through each dataset

(II) split each dataset into train and test sets

(III) build a xgboost regression model

(IV) round the prediction value to nearest integer-example `5000.23` to `5000` and append the rounded values to the test data frames respectively

(V) Export or write out the test sets with the 'pred' column to four individual `.csv` files

See below for my attempt

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import xgboost
import csv as csv
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score,KFold
from sklearn.cross_validation import  train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV   
from collections import OrderedDict

#(I) programmatically import all four datasets- probably using a glob and for loop

filenames = sorted(glob.glob('*/.csv"'))
filenames = filenames[0:4]
for filename in filenames:
    print(filename)

    dataset = pd.read_csv(fname=filename, delimiter=',')
    X, y = dataset.iloc[:, :-1], dataset.iloc[:, -1] 
    
   #(II) split each dataset into train and test sets
  
    train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, y, 
                      test_size = 0.3, random_state = 123) 
    # create a cross-validation scheme
    folds = KFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle = True, random_state = 100)

    # specify range of hyperparameters to tune
    hyper_params = [{'n_features_to_select': list(range(1, 4))}]

    # (III) Build Xgboost regression model
    xgb_r = xg.XGBRegressor(objective ='reg:linear', 
                  n_estimators = 10, seed = 123) 
  
    # Fitting the model 
    xgb_r.fit(train_X, train_y) 
  
    # Predict the model 
    pred = xgb_r.predict(test_X)
    # RMSE Computation 
    rmse = np.sqrt(MSE(test_y, pred)) 
    print("RMSE : % f" %(rmse)) 
    
   # append pred to original test_X and append the rounded values to the test dataframes
   test_X['pred'] = pred
   
   # (IV) round the prediction value to nearest integer  
   test_X['pred'].round(decimals=0) 
    
   #(V) Export or write out the test sets with the 'pred' column to four separate .csv files using the initial file names like this- `Chase_submission.csv`, `Barclays_submission.csv`, `BNP_submission.csv` and `Deutsche_submission.csv`
 
   test_X.to_csv(f'{filename}.csv', index=False))
```

The problem I am having is that my script runs in jupyter (with no errors returned). However, it does not return an output in my working directory.

[image: Script_Image]

Comment: Please update your question to indicate what problem you are encountering when you try this. It's a little too open ended of a question to provide a focused answer to.

Comment: your approach seems ok. what is your question?

Comment: I notice that your last line is outside your for loop but is using a for loop variable `filename`. Could that be your issue?

Comment: @David- I am not getting the desired results that is 4 `csv` files which will include the following columns- `age`, `income`, `creditscore`, `utility_ratio`, `loan_amount` and  `pred` for each exported file. I think there's something I am not catching in my for loop

Comment: @armamut- The approach seems okay, but I am not getting four separate `csv` files with the five initial columns and the prediction `pred` column.  There seems to be something I am not doing right. How would you approach it assuming you have 4 different datasets with exact columns-an example will be highly appreciated

Comment: Are you getting 1 csv instead of 4? If so see my previous comment. Otherwise please add detail to the question to explain exactly what you do get. Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: @David- I used my attempt as a guide, what would be your approach, at this point I am open to other efficient approaches. If you don’t mind, how would you attempt this(if possible, can you share an example- may be with 2 generated  datasets )?

Comment: Your approach looks ok to both me and @armamut. But you havne't addressed my second comment, it appears you're saving the results only after the loop runs and thus only getting the last loop. I asked if you are getting 1 result instead of 4, you haven't answered, I asked you to look at the last line being outside of the for loop, you haven't responded to that question. This comment thread is too long which is ill-advised. You should just edit the question to include more detail specifically responding to these questions and also stating what results you get when you run the code you posted.

Comment: In general when asking questions on stack overflow try to make your questions specific. Asking questions like, "here's my code, can you debug it," or "write this function for me," don't make good questions (they are hard to answer, and not useful to others). It's better to try something, run into a specific problem, and ask how to fix that specific problem. If there are better approaches people will often state so and you might take up follow on questsions in other posts. See how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DavidParks- I have made edits and shared an image of my script, my code runs with no errors returned, however, there's no output file in my working directory

Comment: If it returned no output the obvious check would be whether the glob matched anything, did you output the value of `sorted(glob.glob('*/.csv"'))`? Start adding print statements in there, verify you're actually running the for loop. Print the sizes of variables along the way to ensure you're getting what you expected. Verify each line of code produces the expected result. You should be able to pinpoint a line of code in there that behaves unexpectedly.